# Array reference passed to a function is lost when array.filter is applied

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The idea of this pattern is to manage different arrays. When user clicks on an option it selects/deselects it and option's value is pushed into/filtered from the corresponding array.

I am trying to write the universal method that will manage the array it was called with, at the moment it works fine with pushing values but doesn't work with filtering.

**Angular Component Methods (doesn't work)**

```
 potatoesArray = [];

 manageOptions($event, testingArray) {

  const checkExistence = (array, value) => {
    return !(array.indexOf(value) >= 0)    
  }

  if ($event) {
    // SPAN value
    const optionValue = $event.target.innerText;      

    // Push if value isn't in array
    if (checkExistence(testingArray, optionValue)) {
      testingArray.push(optionValue);      

    // 'Remove' the value if it's in array  
    } else {
      testingArray = testingArray.filter((option) => {
        return option != optionValue;
      })
    }
}
```

**Angular Component Methods (works if referenced to array directly)**

```
 potatoesArray = [];

 manageOptions($event, testingArray) {

  ...

    } else {
      this.potatoesArray = testingArray.filter((option) => {
        return option != optionValue;
      })
    }
}
```

**Note**

```
console.log(testingArray === this.potatoesArray) // true
```

**Template implementation**

```
<div class="option" (click)='manageOptions($event, this.potatoesArray)'>
  <span>OPTION 1</span>
  ...                              
</div>

<div class="option" (click)='manageOptions($event, this.potatoesArray)'>
  <span>OPTION 2</span>                              
  ...
</div>

<div class="option" (click)='manageOptions($event, this.potatoesArray)'>
  <span>OPTION 3</span>                              
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: It always a good idea to let people know any errors you may be getting, in the question, so that one does not have to guess.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan totally agree with you, but no error shows up :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `this` from the template implementation

```
<div class="option" (click)='manageOptions($event, potatoesArray)'>
  <span>OPTION 1</span>
  ...                              
</div>

<div class="option" (click)='manageOptions($event, potatoesArray)'>
  <span>OPTION 2</span>                              
  ...
</div>

<div class="option" (click)='manageOptions($event, potatoesArray)'>
  <span>OPTION 3</span>                              
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I did figure out that is not a problem of angular, but more a javascript behavior here is simplified question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43953320/rewrite-array-from-the-function-using-argument-reference it shows up that it's kind of trick to set new value of an array if it is referenced from an argument.