# Rewrite array from the function. Using argument reference

Tags: javascript

Can you please explain how to worship JavaScript gods and work around this one.

```js
var array = ['old'];
    
function manageArray(targetArray) {
  targetArray = ['new'];
}

manageArray(array);
alert(array);
```

The reason for this is to create a pattern that will have filter logic and instead of declaring explicit methods for each array have one universal to rule over all.

**Desired logic**

```
var numbers = ['1', '2']
var words = ['room', 'car']
var color = ['red', 'blue']

function manageArray(targetArray, value) {
  targetArray = targetArray.filter(existingValue, () => {
    return existingValue != value
  })
}

manageArray(words, 'car');
alert(words);
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here? `targetArray` is scoped to your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to pass your variable by reference. It is sad that Javascript pass  array as value. There are a few ugly workaround.

```
var array = {v: ['old'] };

function manageArray(targetArray) {
  targetArray.v = ['new'];
}

manageArray(array);
```

or

```
var array = ['old'];

function manageArray(targetArray) {
    return ['new'];
}

array = manageArray(array);
```

For further reading:

- [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to access the array if you have your function return it:

```js
var array = ['old'];
    
function manageArray(targetArray) {
  targetArray = ['new'];
  return targetArray
}

array = manageArray(array);
alert(array);
```